# Recommendation for mailing address matching scenario?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, street-address

My SQL server contains 2 tables containing a similar set of fields for a mailing (physical) address. NB these tables are populated before the data gets to my database (can't change that). The set of fields in the tables are similar though not identical - most exist in both tables, some only in one, some the other. The goal is to determine with "high confidence" whether or not two mailing addresses match.

Example fields:

1. Street Number
2. Predirection
3. Street Name
4. Street Suffix
5. Postdirection (one table and not the other)
6. Unit name (one table) v Address 2 (other table) --adds complexity
7. Zip code (length varies in each table 5 v 5+ digits)
8. Legal description

Ideally I'd like to a simple way to call a "function" which returns either a boolean or a confidence level of match (0.0 - 1.0). This call can be made in SQL or Python within my solution; free/open source highly preferred by client.

Among options such as SOUNDEX, DIFFERENCE, Levenshtein distance (all SQL) and usaddress, dedupe (Python) none stand out as a good-fit solution.

Comment: "high confidence" is the problem...you'l have to standardize the addresses in both tables before you can try and match them. You could look at something like Accuzip.com...but like I said you'll first need to standardize the addresses before you try to compare them.

Comment: I agree with @BillRuhl about standardizing both address and then comparing them. Here is one [option](https://smartystreets.com/articles/usps-api), but it is going to cost something.

Comment: Address standardization is trickier that one may think and will require constant monitoring.   Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249742/address-standardization-within-a-database/41249971#41249971

Comment: Can you expand on "The fields in the tables are similar though not identical." -- your answer to this question is important for determining the best course of action.

Comment: Thanks all for responding! @JohnCappelletti your approach using Google Maps API for standardizing seems straightforward and cost effective for us. Please explain needing "constant monitoring." 
After better understanding standardization I will continue with comparison/similarity metrics. Thanks again.

Comment: @KevinR.M. If you create a homegrown method, there will ALWAYS be new exceptions and considerations. I'd suspect you would require an ALERT process for outliers.    Years ago, I created a rather sophisticated linking methodology which out performed Dunn & Bradstreet and even Experian.  Though I was very proud of the process, it would never be 100% or completely defensible.

Answer (score 3):

> Ideally I'd like to a simple way to call a "function" which returns
>   either a boolean or a confidence level of match (0.0 - 1.0).

A similarity metric is what you're looking for. You can use Distance Metrics to calculate similarity. The [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), [Damerau-Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) and Hamming Distance are examples of Distance Metrics.

Given the shortest of the two: **M** the shorter of the two, **N** the longest, and your distance metric (**D**) you can measure string *Similarity* using **(M-D)/N**. You can also use the Longest Common subsequence or Longest Common Substring **(LCS)** to measure similarity by dividing **LCS/N**.

If you can use CLRs I HIGHLY recommend [mdq.similarity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ee633878(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which you can get from [here.](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/accessing-functions-in-master-data-services) It will give a similarity metric using these algorithms:

1. The Damarau-Levenshtein distance (the documentation only says, "Levenshtein" but they are mistaken)
2. The Jaccard Similarity coefficient algorithm.
3. a form of the Jaro-Winkler distance algorithm.
   4 a longest common subsequence algorithm (which grows by one when transpositions are involved)

If performance is important (these metrics can be quite slow depending on what you're feeding them) then I would get familiar with my [Bernie function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440338/does-cross-apply-where-clause-work-before-cross-apply-or-after-on-the-results/58441027#58441027). It's designed to help measure similarity using ***any*** of the aforementioned algorithms much, much faster. Bernie is 100% open source and can be easily re-created in any language (Python, C#, etc.) Ditto my N-Grams function.

You can easily create your own metric using [NGrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams).

For pure T-SQL versions of Levenshtein or the Longest Common Subsequence you can check Phil Factor's blog. (Note these cannot compete with the CLR I mentioned).

I'll stop for now. The best advice can be given after we better understand what is making the strings different (note my question under your comment).

Comment: I clarified my question above. There are 2 data sets (up to 9 eventually). You've given me more to run with regarding similarity metrics. Not sure which one I'll use yet but this sped up my investigation markedly.